# Cannot read property of 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, redux

I went through the Redux tutorial and practicing implementing some of the examples on my own (to ensure I understand how they work).

I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'




const todo = (state, action) => {
    console.log('todo ran')
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    console.log('todos ran')
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state,
                todo(undefined, action)
            ];
    }
}
//Just updated this to include an empty list
let store = createStore(todos, [])


let nextTodoId = 0
const AddTodo = () => {
    let input;

    return (
        <div>
            <input ref={node => {input = node}}/>
            <button onClick = {() => {
                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'ADD_TODO',
                    id: nextTodoId++,
                    text: input.value
                });
                input.value = ''
            }}>
                Add Todo
            </button>
            <ul>
                {store.getState().map(item => 
                    <li key={item.id}> {item.text} </li>
                )}
            </ul>
            <button onClick = {() => console.log(store.getState())}>Print State</button>

        </div>
    )
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <AddTodo />,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

I thought I am passing in an empty state `[]` and that I would map over that. But it seems that `state` is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have missed passing the initial state to the `createStore` call.

Try the following:

```
let store = createStore(todos, [])
```

Comment: hmmm...tried that and still got the same issue. Updating the code.

Comment: Can you maybe put this in a fiddle so that we are not just trading words?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add:

`default:
    return state`

at the bottom of `todos`.